Finding integral limits for the region enclosed by $y=x^2$, $y=1$, and $x=0$
I want to evaluate the following double integral:
$$\iint_D1\;dxdy$$
where, $D$ represent the area enclosed by $y=x^2$, $y=1$, and $x=0$. Here I drew the graph of the region $D$:

I think the integral will be $$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt y}^01\;dxdy$$
But I'm not sure if I'm right. In particular, I doubt that the integral limits are as follows:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{-\sqrt y}1\;dxdy$$

The area you are looking for is the complement of the classic area under the parabola, ie. $1 - \int_0^1 t^2 \textrm{d}t = 2/3$.

@Jean So I believe the limits in the first integral are the correct ones, as I got $2/3$ from that integral.

Your image only shows the half of the actual integral, are you aware of that?

@Dominique The area is enclosed by $y=x^2$, $y=1$, and $x=0$ so I think the image is  fine.

@user1380196: you're right, I was thinking of $y=0$ and $y=1$ instead of $x=0$ and $y=1$. But still, it's a weird way to formulate boundaries.

If you fix $y$, then $-\sqrt y\le x\le 0$ for $y\in [0,1]$. Hence your first option is correct:
$$I=\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt y}^0 \mathrm dx \mathrm dy $$
Note that, since $\iint_D \mathrm dx \mathrm dy=\mu(D) \ge 0$, if the bounds were inverted you'd get a negative integral.

Can you please elaborate on, what does $\mu(D)$ represent?

@user1380196 the measure of $D$. In the plane, it's basically the area
